# SSH tunnel reconnecting after WAN change or server drop

Tags: ssh, debian, ssh-tunnel

I am fighting with autoSSH configuration.

### My setup

1. VPS as a public contact point, clients will access the VPS IP to get to the server
2. My home server running the service. This machine has dualwan connectivity - so it can switch to another ISP if the first one drop. (IP address will change)

I want to make a SSH tunnel that will automatically reconnect when the connectivity is switched or one of those two machines is restarted (or the tunnel drops for whatever reason).

**Both machines runs on Debian 10 64bit with no GUI**

### What I did:

I created a Systemd service that will connect the autossh tunnel at the start of the machine when network is online. You can see my service here: https://paste.brcb.eu/xefobiremy.ini

The autossh command is: 
 `/usr/bin/autossh -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3"  mctunel@remoteIP -p 22 -N -R 25565:localhost:25565 -i /home/mc/fhkey`

### My issue:

Whenever the connectivity switch or somethign goes wrong, the tunnel will not recover. Service will just run without any tries to reconnect. If I restart the service manually, I will get an error that the forwarding cannot connect to port 25565 - the connection was not closed on the VPS side and the port is still "used".

Any idea how to make this work? I can even use other software than autossh, if its better for my situation.

Thanks!